# Why is Ambient Occlusion creating this extra light? (Eevee) (Includes pic)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, ambient-occlusion

Does anyone know why turning AO on is creating this extra light, as well as a sort of bloom effect? This is in Eevee. Thanks.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can't reproduce. Can you share a .blend with an example of this effect?

Comment: @robin I think it may have something to do with the scene being very, very small. That “corridor” is about one fifth the height of the default cube. I think that might be throwing off the AO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is much you can do. To me, it looks like that large amounts of light in your scene are reflecting off objects onto others. What ambient occlusion does it it doesn't only let light fall from the lamp to the object, but it can bounce off objects onto others. This bloom effect might just be light bouncing off the wall onto other (probably reflective) materials.

Just know I am not positive, as I am just basing my prediction of the picture.

Some things you might be able to do is fiddle with the roughness and specular values of the object. Specular values would probably be better, as they break the rules of light physics.

Hope this helps.